# How to track Bugs worked on in Azure devops?

Tags: azure-devops

I'm new to Azure Devops. If a bug is assigned to me and after fixing it, the Tester closes it by assigning it to his name, how will I track how many bugs I have worked on over a period of time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either probably find the details under "My activity" of the work item area.

[image]

Or you can create a custom query to find bugs that were ever assigned to you.

[image]